# trying to use a negative margin in css on a list

Tags: css, list, margins

I have been trying for an hour to get a list in a sidebar of WordPress to have a negative margin. Fooled around with margins, padding, sidebar placement in the php files... But the link images just keep disappearing behind the background.

Here's the page where I'm working: http://kirahenschel.com/

This is what I am trying to achieve:
http://emgraphics.net/kira/idea2-11.jpg

Ideally I'd also like that sidebar to be a finite height so the white boxes on the bottom spread, but I can cope with them being off to the right.

Anyone have any ideas? Neg margins are working fine on the logo, so it is just a list thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're merely trying to get the list to be bumped to the left, why not use a CSS positioning property?  Negative margins can get really wonky, and are (most likely) unneeded in this application.

```
#nameoflistdiv {
    left: -20px;
}
```

You may also need to change the value of your div's position element, but this will bump your div and everything in it left, overlapping the container div.

If that doesn't answer your question, can you post the HTML and CSS you are using?  The CSS code

```
margin-left: -20px;
```

really should work in this application as well, so show us what you've got.

Comment: yep, it should but the genius below pointed out that there was a hidden tag elsewhere in the code.  d'oh! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your negative margin is working as expected. The reason the images are getting cut off is because you have set `overflow:hidden` on the `#main` container. If you remove that property your images will appear.

```
#main {
    background: url("images/blend.png") repeat-x scroll center top #2765CA;
    clear: both;
    height: 630px;
    overflow: hidden; /* delete this line */
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Elaine: This might seem like a silly question, but if my solution was the one to fix the issue, then why have you marked the other answer as correct?

Comment: Sorry - that solution did work but ended up screwing up some other parts of the page, which I didn't notice right away.